pingInterval not working in socket.io for me for recovery
I'm following these docs: https://socket.io/docs/v4/connection-state-recovery#usage.
And the example given: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/socketio/socket.io/tree/main/examples/connection-state-recovery-example/esm?file=index.js
To test out the connection state recovery feature in socket.io but I'm confused because I thought socket.io handled ping pong emits automatically, so I figured setting pingInterval: 1000 would replace this line used in the example:
setInterval(() => {
  io.emit("ping", new Date().toISOString());
}, 1000);

But the recovery isn't working when using:
const io = new Server(server, { // for work with socket.io
  cors: corsOptions,
  pingInterval: 1000,
  connectionStateRecovery: {
    maxDisconnectionDuration: 2 * 60 * 1000, // 2 mins backup
    skipMiddlewares: true,
  },
});

without the setInterval...
edit: I found some possibly useful info
const socket = io(
  process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER || "http://localhost:3001",
  {
    reconnectionDelay: 5000, // defaults to 1000
    reconnectionDelayMax: 5000, // defaults to 5000
  }
);
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.recovered); // true only for setInterval method
});
socket.io.on("ping", () => {
  console.log("ping from pingInterval only");
});
socket.on("ping", () => {
  console.log("ping from setInterval only");
});


Upon further inspection, it seems this line in the docs is why... "For the recovery to succeed, the server must send at least one event, in order to initialize the offset on the client side." I figured "ping" was a special event but I guess any will do, but is needed:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xnkned?file=index.js,index.html
